# Setting an environment as the first location in PATH

Tags: linux, bash, virtualenv, sudo, tmux

I use tmux and I'm trying to have it automatically activate a python virtual env every time I open it or make a new pane.

I can get it to work properly by just adding the `source activate venv` line to my ~/.bashrc, but the problem is that it's not the first directory in the path and so the usual `(venv) $` does not appear in my bash PS1 line.

If I do `echo $PATH` I get
`/usr/local/cuda/bin:/users/me/conda_envs/venv/bin:...`

It seems that the `/usr/local/cuda/bin` is added to my path in the /etc/profile, but it does so AFTER the bashrc files are run, which I believe is the problem.

/etc/profile:

```
if [ "$PS1" ]; then
  if [ "$BASH" ] && [ "$BASH" != "/bin/sh" ]; then
    # The file bash.bashrc already sets the default PS1.
    # PS1='\h:\w\$ '
    if [ -f /etc/bash.bashrc ]; then
      . /etc/bash.bashrc
    fi
  else
    if [ "`id -u`" -eq 0 ]; then
      PS1='# '
    else
      PS1='$ '
    fi
  fi
fi

# The default umask is now handled by pam_umask.
# See pam_umask(8) and /etc/login.defs.

if [ -d /etc/profile.d ]; then
  for i in /etc/profile.d/*.sh; do
    if [ -r $i ]; then
      . $i
    fi
  done
  unset i
fi
```

The problem is that I don't have sudo access on this machine to change the order of those system files being sourced.
Since I activate my venv in my user `~/.bashrc` file shouldn't that occur after the global files in /etc/ are sourced? But it doesn't seem like that since the `cuda` directory is always first in the path.

Is it possible for me to source the venv AFTER `cuda` gets added to the path?

Comment: It's not clear how your `.bashrc` is being sourced *at all*. If `/etc/profile` is sourced, it means `tmux` is (as per the default) starting a login shell for each pane, and `.bashrc` is only sourced for non-login interactive shells. Does `/etc/bash.bashrc` source it? (Note that *that* file is not a standard `bash` configuration file; it's just something used by your local `/etc/profile` file.

Comment: `~/.bashrc` is sourced in `~/.profile`